# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED using fontawesome

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Here is the code inside `head` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" 
integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
```

In console I'm getting the following:

> GET https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe problem with your network.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" 
integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" 
crossorigin="anonymous">

<i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>
```